# how to change the text file to jmx file whose properties has been changed to text?

Tags: file, text, jmeter, notepad

I have .jmx Jmeter file with me. But unknowingly the properties of the jmx file has been changed to .txt. How could I revoke this to jmx file again. I am not able to open the jmx in jmeter. I have changed the file extension and change the properties to support the jmeter file but it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter can open all file types

```
Click File -> Open -> Choose myJmx.jmx.txt
```

and you can work and execute it

If you file still isn't opened then change the open with:

```
Right click on file -> Open With -> Browse to jmeter-t.bat
```

Comment: I have my jmx file as myJMXfile.jmx and it's file type also showing as JMX document. Bu it is open as notepad document as the properties got changed to text file. Still I couldn't open my file in JMeter. How to rectify this?

Comment: Right click on file -> Open With -> Browse to jmeter-t.bat

Comment: You can upvote by click on the arrow up left to the answer